# Changing font size with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to change the font size of the letters "Se Habla Espanol".

I'm relatively new to JavaScript. And during the process of the me playing with the website I got into the following problem.

This is what I currently have:

```
<body>

<font color="yellow">
<script>
function blinker() {
$('.blinking').fadeOut(500);
$('.blinking').fadeIn(500);
}

setInterval(blinker, 1000);

</script>

<center>

<p class="blinking">se habla Espanol</p>

</center>


</font>

</body>
```

I was thinking of using the following code but it seems that it is only responsive to HTML and not javascript

```
<font size="+2">This is bigger text.</font>
```

This is what I had in mind so my work is not really accurate and everything is taken from the internet

--This is what I attempted to do but didn't work:

```
<center>
<font size="+2">
<p class="blinking">se habla Espanol</p>
</font>

</center>
```

Comment: seems more like jquery.

Comment: Both `<font>` and `<center>` are deprecated due to preffered approach is use css

Comment: @Both so would be  your recommendation to best approach the adjust size ?

Comment: JavaScript is not, nor will ever be, Java.

Answer (score 0):

If your already using jQuery why not use a selector with css

```
$('.blinking').css('font-size' ,' 22px');
// or what ever font-size  you would like
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right, you can just add a css style to the tag in jquery:

```
$(".blinking").css( "font-size", "7px" );
```

And add the css:

```
.blinking
{
    -webkit-transition: font 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: font  0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: font 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: font 0.3s ease;
}
```

if you want to change you can set again for a smaller value

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you tagged this as jquery/java when it doesn't have neither...

Assuming we have a class called `.upFontByTwo` and that you're using jquery, you can do something like...

```
//Evaluates current font-size of said class to string
var currentFontSize = $(".upFontByTwo").css("font-size"));
//(currentFontSize == '22px')


//Changes it from string to its actual value
currentFontSize = parseInt(currentFontSize);
//(currentFontSize == 22)

//Makes the font-size for the same class the same size +2
$(".upFontByTwo").css("font-size", (currentFontSize+2) + 'px');
```

Also don't use the `<center>` tag nor the `<font>` tag. They're both deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using Jquery.
Don't put  outside it's make html more complicated. Just make attr for

tag

```
<p class="blinking" data-addition-size="2">se habla Espanol</p>
```

Then just add

```
var current-size = parseInt($('.blinking').css('font-size'), 10);
var new-size =  current-size + $('.blinking').data("addition-size");
$('.blinking').css("font-size", new-size + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to manipulate the elements with JS / JQuery, all you need is CSS and then you can remove a lot of your HTML tags:

```js
// keep your JS as it is
function blinker() {
  $('.blinking').fadeOut(500);
  $('.blinking').fadeIn(500);
}
setInterval(blinker, 1000);
```

```css
/* add this CSS to your page, either in the document's header or in an external file */
.blinking {
  font-size: 2em; /* use twice the "normal" size */
  text-align: center; /* align text centered */
  /*color: yellow;*/ /* put into comment to avoid damage to your eyes */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- now you only need the <p> tag, remove all your <center> and <font> tags -->
<p class="blinking">se habla Espanol</p>
```